# Trying to create a menu with jQuery but my code isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am trying to create a menu with jQuery as in when the user mouseover an element the menu would show up and would hide when user moves the mouse away.

**My html code:**

```
<div class="span8 img">
   <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3198/2978120072_ca00381e08.jpg" alt="" width="550px" height="368px">
   <div class="like-box">Like</div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.like-box {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    width: 94%;
    bottom: -1px;
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.img').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.like-box').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).parent().siblings('.like-box').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        })
    });
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `mouseleave` event out of `img` mouseover, because binding event within mouseover, bind the mouseleave event to `like-box` each time, which is not good and unnecessary.

```
$('.like-box').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
})
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    $(this)  // this point to img
      .next('.like-box')  // point to like-box
      .css('display', 'block');       
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4gGwk/1/)**

**NOTE:**

- `$('.img')` should be `$('img')` because you image has no class called `img`, `.` selector is use for access class. read about **[selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** and also [**class-selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.like-box')
```

`$(this)` is `img`, the `parent()` is `div.span8.img`, and the `siblings()` are...none.

Try with:

```
$(this).next('.like-box')
```

Comment: ok it worked i had the selector name wrong. but it doesnt hide on mouseout. but i have the code $(this).next('.like-box').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });